# Significato di "passata sul raspo" in questa frase

Tags: meaning, idioms

Nel romanzo *La malora*, di Beppe Fenoglio, ho letto:

> La servente arrivò prima dello sperato: veniva dalla langa di Castino ed era ancora parente di Tobia, quantunque parentela **passata sul raspo**; si chiamava Fede e andava per i diciotto anni.

Sapreste spiegarmi cosa significa "parentela passata sul raspo"? Ho cercato alla voce "raspo" in parecchi dizionari  (sul dizionario dei modi di dire Hoepli non appare tale voce), ma non ho trovato nulla che abbia senso in questo contesto.

Comment: Anch’io non ho trovato nulla di nulla; l’unica supposizione che mi sembra appropriata col testo citato è che _passata sul raspo_ voglia significare una parentela molto alla lontana.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Passata sul raspo" vuol dire che non è una parentela stretta.

Il "raspo" in questo caso è uno strumento che fa da setaccio per togliere le olive dagli alberi senza staccare i rami e le foglie.

Si intende quindi, in senso dialettale abbastanza arcaico, che la parentela è stata passata al setaccio ed è quindi molto "scremata" (nel senso che sono passate molte generazioni o molti gradi di separazione rispetto al "parente" in questione).

Comment: Benvenuto/a su Italian.SE e grazie della risposta!